# Map Dictionary Keys to add values - Swift

Tags: swift, dictionary, key

I have two dictionaries: a data dict and a results dict

```
var data    = ["flushes": 0.0, "times": 0.0, "glasses": 0.0, "showers": 0.0, "brushings": 0.0, "loads": 0.0, "washings": 0.0, "baths": 252.0, "dishes": 0.0]
let results = ["flushes": 21.0, "times": 0.0, "glasses": 0.0, "showers": 150.0, "brushings": 4.0, "loads": 0.0, "washings": 5.0, "baths": 0.0, "dishes": 9.0]
```

I am wondering how to add like values based on key and have only one dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `data` is mutable, this should do it:

```
data.merge(results, uniquingKeysWith: { $0 + $1 })
```

Comment: That worked! thanks!

Comment: `data.merge(results, uniquingKeysWith: +)` should also work.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Ole`s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51586013/5501940), at this point there are two other -syntactic sugar- options:

You could type it as:

```
data.merge(results, uniquingKeysWith: +)
```

Or as a *trailing closure* syntax:

```
data.merge(results) { $0 + $1 }
```

Hence:

```
print(data)
/*
 ["flushes": 21.0,
  "times": 0.0,
  "glasses": 0.0,
  "showers": 150.0,
  "brushings": 4.0,
  "loads": 0.0,
  "washings": 5.0,
  "baths": 252.0,
  "dishes": 9.0]
*/
```