# Swift 4 equivalent of Kotlin "anonymous class" notation

Tags: android, ios, swift, kotlin

I've been writing in Kotlin for a while, and I get used to use next pattern:

```
variable.addSomething(object: TargetType() { ...code... })
```

or

```
var variable = object: TargetType() { ...code... }
```

(if i'm not missing something)

Is it possible to somehow use this pattern in Swift ? And how is it called ? :)

**Edit**:
What I actually want to do - to store preconfigured RxSwift.SingleEvent in a let / var inside object and reuse it later  multiple times.

In code, as I imagine, it should look like that:

```
private var observer = SingleEvent<Response>(ok_callback, error_callback) { 
      override success(el: Element) {
             ok_callback(el)
             super.success(el)
    }
      override error(er: Error) {
           self.onErrorRetry(er, callback)
    }
}
```

And if retry after some magic works - simply call my callback and return back :)

Comment: This "object: Closure" is called an "anonymous class".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Anonymous class in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24408068/anonymous-class-in-swift)

Comment: @user28434 language which was used in '14 has quite changed. Actually Swift 4 is completely different from that which used in marked answer (despite that fact that it was throwing an error at compile-time)

Comment: @Pawel It would be called that in Java, but in Kotlin it's an ["object expression"](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html).

Comment: I think there is no equivalent concept in Swift 4, even when there are ways to emulate it as depicted in the question that @user28434 linked. Your best bet is to use a plain, old, and boring struct/class that implements the protocol/interface you're interested in

Answer (score 1):

Its seems to be ***trailing closure***. Adapted from [Swift programming language - Closures](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html):

> If you need to pass a closure expression to a function as the
>   function’s *final argument* and the closure expression is long, it can
>   be useful to write it as a trailing closure instead. A trailing
>   closure is written after the function call’s parentheses, even though
>   it is still an argument to the function. When you use the trailing
>   closure syntax, you don’t write the argument label for the closure as
>   part of the function call.

**Let's code it:**

Simply, all you have to do is just to create a function which its last argument is a closure:

```
func doSomething(firstParameter: Any, closure: () -> Void) { }
```

thus you could call it as:

```
doSomething(firstParameter: "whatever") {
    // ...
}
```

Nothing special goes here, it is a cool feature from the Swift language to "trail" `closure` parameter if its the last one in the function signature.

In case of initialization, it is almost the same:

```
struct MyObject {
    init(firstParameter: Any, closure: () -> Void) { }
}

let variable = MyObject(firstParameter: "whatever") {  }
```

Certainly, this pattern is followed by many other functions in the language, but here is an example of the `merge` method for the Dictionary, you could recognize how you could type it in more than one way as mentioned in the answers of: [Map Dictionary Keys to add values - Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51585897/map-dictionary-keys-to-add-values-swift).

---

**Update:**

If you are aiming to use it as constant/variable -to be passed for a function for example-, you could do it like this:

```
let variable: (String) -> Void = { name in
    print("The name is: \(name)!")
}
```

At this point, `variable` type is `(String) -> Void` which means that its a constant that could be passed somewhere else; Consider the following method:

```
func doSomething(closure: (String) -> Void) {
    closure("Nikita")
}
```

Because `doSomething` takes a parameter of type `(String) -> Void`, you could do:

```
doSomething(closure: variable) // The name is: Nikita!
```

instead of calling it as:

```
doSomething { name in
    print("The name is: \(name)!")
}
```

which prevents the boilerplate code.

Comment: Actually, It's not exactly the same, cause with trailing closure, inside of calling function you can only "call" this closure, but with, as @Pawel mentioned, anonymous class - you receive a whole object inside calling function, and you will be available to choose whatever you want to do with it, rather calling its methods or setting parameters.

Comment: @NikitaYankov mmm, seems that I misunderstand something here, could you please elaborate?

Comment: I edited my question - it's impossible to format a code in a comment :C

Comment: Kotlin has trailing closure syntax, but this question doesn't show it. This is about declaring a full object that implements all the methods of the given interface (not necessarily a SAM interface) and may contain property declarations as well.